# how to get real counts of the comments in facebook api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have used Facebook graph API to fetch some comments on my post .. it works very well but when i add the `?summary=true` it should give me the total count ..

actually it gives me the count but its a different number from the comments count

Im not getting all the comments with replies so the replies is not counted

i used the API to display all comments on a vue js app i created locally

have no idea what should i do to get the right count from the summary parameter

it gives me  :

```
data{} // data object with 5500 items

summary": {
"order": "chronological",
"total_count": 5900,
"can_comment": false
}
```

I expect the `total_count` matches the count of data items

Am i missing something ? or the `total_count` is not meant to be the count of the data?

I'm a bit confused

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add in a code sample in the future. However, in this case I would assume that the API is meant to only give the top-level comments and not the replies.

Answer (score 0):

I did miss something on the documentation ..

it says :

> Note: total_count can be greater than or equal to the actual number of comments returned due to comment privacy or deletion.

I guess that's the answer for my question

thanks